# csvsimple misplaced \omit. \multispan when using multicolumn for entire row

Tags: texmaker

...

Hello, everyone!

I have tried to search for the even only similar problem, but with no luck.

I have got following error:

*! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit
\@multispan
l.1113 }
I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of
an alignment.*

for the following code (below the 'working example', as **Peter Ebelsberger** asked):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{misreco_train.csv}
first;second;third
speaker1_cmd;;
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{DarkBrown}{rgb}{0.4,0.2,0}
\definecolor{LightSalmon}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.6}
\definecolor{Salmon}{rgb}{1,0.6,0.4}

\csvstyle{Misrecognition}{
tabular={|ccc|},
separator=semicolon,
table head=\hline\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{DarkBrown}{\color{white} header text}},
late after head=\\\hline\rowcolor{Salmon},
late after line=\csvifoddrow{\\\hline\rowcolor{Salmon}}{\\\hline\rowcolor{LightSalmon}},
respect underscore=true
}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{here is my caption}
\csvreader[Misrecognition]%
{misreco_train.csv}%
{1=\first,2=\second,3=\third}%
{
  \csviffirstrow%
  {
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\second}{}}%
    {\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{Salmon}\first}}% this is the line causing the error
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\third}{}}%
        {\first & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{Salmon}\second}}%
        {\first & \second & \third}%
    }%
  }%
  {\first & \second & \third}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The problem occurs if my CSV file has got only one data row with one item:

**CSV file content:**

```
first;second;third % this is the header
one_item;; % this is the first 3-column row with only one item
```

I have partially figured it out that the problem is when I try to use multicolumn for entire row.
Putting the '\' before multicolumn is helping with an error, but it isn't solving the issue, because it is just adding some additional unformatted space between header and the first row.

As a workaroung I am using following modyfication:

```
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{Salmon}\first}
```

I suspect the csvsimple messing the things up, but just can't find the solution.

EDIT: **egreg** has pointed, the csvreader is adding some unexpandable tokens. Is there a workaround for this, e.g. by using csvloop instead csvreader (which is actually (AFAIK) some kind of a wrapper for csvloop?)

EDIT2: Thank you, **Thomas F. Sturm** for your answer, but unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as the solution yet, because after adapting it to my code exactly as you have pointed in the code example, there still is a problem with rendering the table in PDF document. There is a little white space in the right of the table header. It looks like, the first row starts in the header line...
Please, see the picture below:

[image: generated table]

P.S. version of my texmaker is 3.2

EDIT3: The CSV file can look like:

```
first;second;third
item1;;
```

or

```
first;second;third
item1;item2;
```

or

```
first;second;third
item1;item2;item3
```

or

```
first;second;third
item1;item2;item3
item4;;
```

...and so on. But, never like this:

```
first;second;third
item1;;
item2;item3;item4;
```

So, the next row is present only if all previous ones are maximally filled.

Comment: Would you add a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: what do you mean by Minimal Working Example? I have written, in my question, that to workaround the issue it is enought to replace the error line of: "\multicolumn{3}..." with "{& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{cellcolor{Salmon}\first}}"

Comment: I would like to copy and paste the code and play around. You provided a part of a full compileable code.

Comment: I don't think it's ever possible to have `\multicolumn` in the first column in any `csvsimple` table. The loop code puts unexpandable tokens in the input stream which start making a cell, so it's impossible to have `\multicolumn` any more.

Comment: For EDIT2: The white space should not be there using my answer code exactly. It is added, if some `%` are removed from my code...

Comment: For EDIT3: This is a different problem, because the code only deals with row 1 being special.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas! For EDIT2 - yes, the problem was between the chair and the desk ;P Which means - I forgot about one percent sign. Now it works and with unhidden pleasure, I am marking your answer as a solution :)

Comment: For EDIT3 - it doesn't matter. It was just my clarification about the nature of that specific data in my CSV file :)

Comment: Good to hear that it works now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the cause of the problem is not that `csvreader` adds some unexpandable tokens. This can be seen by removing the `csvreader` code and writting the table directly. The following code gives the same error message:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{DarkBrown}{rgb}{0.4,0.2,0}
\definecolor{LightSalmon}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.6}
\definecolor{Salmon}{rgb}{1,0.6,0.4}

\def\first{START}
\def\second{}
\def\third{}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{normal table}
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
  \hline\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{DarkBrown}{\color{white} header text}}\\\hline\rowcolor{Salmon}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\second}{}}%
  {\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{Salmon}\first}}% this is the line causing the error
  {%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\third}{}}%
      {\first & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{Salmon}\second}}%
      {\first & \second & \third}%
  }%
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You cannot put an `\ifthenelse` before doing a `\multicolumn`.

So, the code has to be changed a little bit. The following works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{misreco_train.csv}
first;second;third
speaker1_cmd;;
A;B;C
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{DarkBrown}{rgb}{0.4,0.2,0}
\definecolor{LightSalmon}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.6}
\definecolor{Salmon}{rgb}{1,0.6,0.4}

\csvstyle{Recognition}{
  tabular={|ccc|},
  separator=semicolon,
  table head=\hline\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{DarkBrown}{\color{white} header text}},
  late after head=,
  late after line=\csvifoddrow{\\\hline\rowcolor{Salmon}}{\\\hline\rowcolor{LightSalmon}},
  respect underscore=true
}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{here is my caption}
\ttfamily
\csvreader[Recognition]%
{misreco_train.csv}%
{1=\first,2=\second,3=\third}%
{%
  \csviffirstrow%
  {%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\second}{}}%
    {\\\hline\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{Salmon}\first}}%
    {%
      \\\hline\rowcolor{Salmon}\first
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\third}{}}%
        {& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{Salmon}\second}}%
        {& \second & \third}%
    }%
  }%
  {\first & \second & \third}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that I inserted a `\ttfamily` to make the underscore visible.

[image]

Comment: Of course I tried with an expandable test instead of `\ifthenelse`, but got the same result; indeed, placing the ``\hline\\`` *inside* `\csviffirstrow` is a workaround, but the problem *is* that `\csvreader` puts unexpandable things in the input stream.

Comment: So, repeating my question: is there some way to solve my problem using csvloop instead of csvreader? And, if yes, could you point me some example?

Comment: @egreg You may be right about `\csvreader` to put unexpandable things in the input string, but the problem of the OPs code was not caused by this (as my example shows).

Comment: @Norethel No, changing to `\csvloop` makes not difference compared to `\csvreader`.